# How to put rest of uniques values in array if condition is not equal using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different uniques values( X, Y) which I have already done so far. I want to put the remaining uniques values in array if condition `x<>y` is not equal and need to create a workbook with array values(rest of uniques values).

Ex:

```
X               Y
SAP           Siemens
Siemens       otto
Otto          Allianz AG
Accenture     Oracle
Oracle        Capgemini
TCS           Daimler
Infosys       Akka
```

I already have workbook as "Siemens.xlsx", "Oracle.xlsx","Otto.xlsx". Now i need the rest of unique values of column Y in array. My expected result should be "Akka.xlsx", "Allainz AG. xlsx", "Daimler.xlsx".

Code:

```
Sub array()

    Dim y as range
    Dim c as integer
    Dim Lastrow_Y As Integer
    Dim Lastrow_X As Integer
    Dim rngFilter_Y as range
    Dim rngCopy as range
    Dim NewBook as workbook

    With Master_workbook.Worksheets("FBI")
            Sheets("FBI").Columns("C:C").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
             CopyToRange:=.Range("AZ1"), Unique:=True
             Lastrow_Y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp).Row
   End with

   With Master_workbook.Worksheets("WWF")
            Sheets("WWF").Columns("d:d").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
             CopyToRange:=.Range("AY1"), Unique:=True
             Lastrow_X = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp).Row
   End with

    For c = 2 To Lastrow_Y
                    Set y = Master_workbook.Sheets("FBI").Range("AZ" & c)
                    Set x = Master_workbook.Sheets("WWF").Range("AY" & c) 
                        If x = y Then
                        set NewBook = workbooks.add
                            with NewBook 
                              .Title = y    NewBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "www"
                             With rngFilter_Y

                                    .AutoFilter field:=32, Criteria1:="<>(a)  0 - 360", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                                    .AutoFilter field:=37, Criteria1:=y.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

                                    Set rngCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                                                        .AutoFilter ' Switch off AutoFilter
                             End With
                        .SaveAs Filename:= Y & ".xlsx"

                         rngCopy.Copy NewBook.Worksheets("www").Cells(1, 1)

                        Else
                        End If
       Next    

    End sub
```

I would really appreciate if anyone help me out of this.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to achieve and there are a number of issues with your code, including using x when it's never declared, initialised or set to anything, using Lastrow_Y without ever setting it to the last row...  First all the issues need fixed, and then if you can explain clearly what it is you want to achieve and what you have tried to do it, we can assist.

Comment: Where is `d` set before this line? `Set x = Master_workbook.Sheets("WWF").Range("AY" & d)`  Was this meant to be `c`?  You should really use more meaningful variable names so that it's clear what each variable represents.

Comment: @Dave  still is there anything to be clear? could you please let me know.

Comment: You have given code which presumably doesn't do what you want it to -- what is the actual problem with the code? Is there any specific issue beyond the fact that it doesn't work? Also -- maybe put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and see if it compiles. The comments make it clear that you aren't using that. For code of this complexity that is almost asking for a bug.

Comment: @JohnColeman The code works fine but When I run the code it should create a new workbook with the names of `Y` column which are not in `X` column rather it creating again with the names in the `Y` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like it'd be a lot easier to check the current folder for which files you have already created, then just create the ones in range Y that aren't already there?

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim folder : Set folder = fso.GetFolder(<path to your .xlsx files here>)
Dim file, fileNames, lastRowY, row, checkFile, newBook
For Each file in folder.Files
    If Right(file.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Then
        fileNames = fileNames & file.Name & ";"         ' will give a list of all filenames
    End If
Next

With Master_workbook.Worksheets("FBI")
       lastRowY = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AY").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For row = 2 to lastRowY
    checkFile = Master_workbook.Worksheets("FBI").Range("AY").Value
    If Instr(fileNames, checkFile) = 0 Then
       Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
       ' do whatever with newBook
       newBook.SaveAs (checkFile & ".xlsx")
       newBook.Close
    End If
Next
```

Comment: its working perfect. Thank you vey much for your help. Is there any other way to get folder without giving the path, `Set folder = fso.GetFolder(<path to your .xlsx files here>)`? please let me know

Comment: every month i need to run this code. I have to change the path in the code  everytime instead of changing the code, it would be better to put something else.

Comment: or define a new folder each month? Start by defining the folder name you want to use with (for example) `folderName = "C:\temp\" & MonthName(Month(Now),True) & Year(Now)` followed by a `objFSO.CreateFolder(folderName)` so that if it's run once a month it creates a folder (currently it'd be "May2016") for you to place the work into?

Comment: I have some problem with the code which you have written. I have modified your code according to my need but now i need that if the workbook or file is existed it should have to re-execute the file or workbook again rather its executing only once, if i run the macro multiple times. could you please help me out.

Comment: I haven't seen what you modified the code to be so can't really advise on that... perhaps post a new question with the code included so the full context is given?

Comment: Now I have edited your code. and I want to see the newbook_scm to be executed again when I run the macro for the first time it works fine but if i ran the macro for multiple times its not replace the newbook_scm with old one.